How to change OS icon to Tuxedo OS in Powerlevel10k (Zsh)?
I'm using Tuxedo OS with Powerlevel10k in Zsh, and the terminal(konsole) shows the default Linux penguin icon.
I'm using the JetBrainsMono Nerd Font. How can I change this to display a Tuxedo OS logo or something close to it?
Thanks!
I know I can customize the icon using: typeset -g POWERLEVEL9K_OS_ICON_CONTENT_EXPANSION='⭐'
